# Handheld iPhone Android Specific CSS not working at all

Tags: android, iphone, css

I am trying to create specific CSS for handheld devices, and I feel like I've tried every way possible with no effect.

The reason I need to do this is so that handheld devices to not use fancybox but instead open the link in a new tab.

To do this in the div there are 2 UL's, each with a class (screen & handheld).

I want the handheld ul to be hidden on desktops and the screen ul to be hidden on handhelds which should be working using display: none on each.

To get the device specific CSS to work I've tried using seperate css files in the HTML header such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/master.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="css/handheld.css" />
```

or, within the master.css file:

```
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
    .screen { display: none !important; }
    }
```

but this does not work. Android always seems to use the UL that includes the fancybox class and thus loads up fancybox every time.

I've tried it in multiple Android browsers (Opera, stock and Dolphin).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with this page:

http://htmldog.com/test/handheld.html

On my android (2.1 unfortunately) it does not work in the default browser. In Opera Mobile it works for me. (I am using latest version for that, of course.)

Update: Sorry, it seems to work only in Opera Mini, not Opera Mobile. (Did I really tap the wrong browser before???)

And http://caniuse.com/#search=@media says that Opera Mobile and Mini supports @media (but says nothing currently about "@media handheld").

It looks like a troublesome area. Maybe it is better to rely on JavaScript for choosing styles? (And automate the process of creating that JavaScript.)